# Why is my text stroke overlapping the text color?

Tags: html, css

## The problem:

I would like my text stroke to  not overlap on mobile the white that is the text color / text fill color. If you look at the following pictures the first picture is mobile and the second picture is web. I would like the header text to always look like the second image.

### I have tried:

- All combinations of the following:

  1. I have tried setting fill to the white color
  2. I have tried setting the fill to transparent and the regular text color to white
  3. No fill and text color to white
- I have tried using :after sudo element to display the fill color but I am not experienced enough to get that to work

## Code:

```html
<h1
            className={`${Styles.minHeightForSymmetry}`}
// this just sets min-height to 9.7rem @min-width768px
            style={{
              textAlign: "center",
              fontSize: "calc(8px + 1vw)",
              fontFamily: "sans-serif",
              color: "white",
            }}
          >
            <span
              style={{
                fontFamily: "sans-serif",
                fontSize: "calc(18px + 1vw)",
                color: "white",
              }}
              className={`${Styles.letterBorder}`}
            >
              Quick Overview of WAR Zone
            </span>{" "}
            <br /> The world&apos;s most fast and efficient match making
            software
          </h1>
```

```css
/* hope fully this will solve the porlem of the stroke overlappong the white text */
.letterBorder {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #000; /* for Chrome and Safari */
  text-stroke: 2px #000; /* for other browsers */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white; /* for Chrome and Safari */
  text-fill-color: white; /* for other browsers */
  text-align: center;
  text-wrap: balance;
  color: transparent; /* Hide the original text color */
}
```

### I apologize for large images, but it makes it easier to see the header text

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post the css styles your using?

Comment: Yes omg im sorry

Comment: It looks like you are using something other than HTML there in your markup. Can you please post the compiled, rendered-in-a-browser HTML instead? See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.letterBorder {
    <YOUR SAME STYLES>
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 
        -1px -1px 0 #000,  
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

Try this out and let me know if it works. It basically creates a fake shadow that will act as an outline.

Comment: Yes, this seems more reliable although it looks weird as you try to increase the amount of the outline. But this is what I wanted anyway thank you for taking the time to help me! Is stroke not reliable to use? There was another question that was similar where the person's solution was also to bail on stroke and just use shadow instead.

Comment: -webkit-text-stroke is known to give problems, its super finicky and 7/10 times it just wont do what you want on mobile